# Transpose or Transform Row to Column in map

Tags: java, apache-spark

everibody! I'm working with Spark using Java 8. I'm using Dataset for store the data. My objective is apply subtract operation in JavaRDD pair, however the row output  is:
JavaRDD rdd1:

```
[[3]]
[[5]]
[[2]]
```

JavaRDD rdd2:
    [[[2, 1, 10]]]

Is impossible perform set operations. The rdd1 was extracted using the snippet code below, from Dataset:

```
JavaRDD<Row> rdd1 =  
    graphFind.
    filter(String.format("a.id == %s",node)).
    select("b").toJavaRDD();
```

the rdd2 was created using the RowFactory from a Integer Array, as shown below:

```
JavaRDD<Row> rdd2 = level.map(r ->{
    List<Integer> array=r.getArrayNodes();
    Row = RowFactory.create(Arrays.asList(array));
    return row;});
```

I tried different approaches as flatmap, but I had no success.

Thanks!